# A method that can take an array of integer in String format and return the average of those numbers

Tags: java, arrays, csv

First time asking a question....

Okay so I have a .csv and I have made a string array from it. I want to make a method that takes the numbers from the string array and returns the average from each line. This is the code I have to far.

```
 while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

        line = scan.nextLine();
        items = line.split(",");

        out += String.format("%10s", items[0]);
        out += "\t";

        for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {

            out += processData(items[i]);
            out += String.format("%.1s",items[1]);
            out += "\t";

        }

        out += " \n";


    }

    scan.close();
    System.out.println(out);

}

public static double processData(String total) {
    String[] val = total.split(" ");
    double[] array = new double[val.length];
    double lineCount = 0;
    double ave = 0;
    double temp =0;

    for (int i = 0; i < val.length; ++i) {
         lineCount++;
         array[i] += Double.parseDouble(val[i]);
         temp += array[i];
         ave = temp/lineCount;
    }
        return ave;

}
```

and this is what the output is.

```
  elephant  651.06  664.06  660.06  664.06  666.06  665.06  655.06  661.06  657.06   
chimpanzee  242.02  245.02  241.02  230.02  237.02  245.02  247.02  232.02  245.02  234.02   
    gerbil  23.02   26.02   22.02   26.02   22.02   22.02   23.02   24.02   23.02   24.02    
   gorilla  257.02  259.02  256.02  257.02  257.02  255.02  259.02  258.02   
   leopard  94.09   95.09   92.09   95.09   95.09   93.09   93.09   93.09   92.09   95.09    
      orca  543.05  547.05  540.05  485.05  552.05  502.05  551.05
```

This is what the ideal output should be.

```
elephant   660.3
chimpanzee 239.8
gerbil     23.5
gorilla    257.3
leopard    93.7
orca       531.4
```

Comment: The logic of this for loop ````for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++)```` is wrong because you are calling ````processData```` on each item of the line, but rather you should call ````processData```` once for each line

Comment: Yes that is correct but I don't know how to separate it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need to print the average and first column

```
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    line = scan.nextLine();
    items = line.split(",");

    strBuilder.append(items[0]);
    strBuilder.append("\t");
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < items.length; i++) {
       sum += Double.parseDouble(items[i])
    }

    strBuilder.append(sum/(items.length-1));
    strBuilder.append("\n");
}

scan.close();
System.out.println(out.toString());
```

If you are using `java8` then;

```
private static String processLine(String[] items) {
  StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder(items[0]);
  strBuilder.append("\t");
  double sum = Arrays.stream(items)
    .skip(1)
    .mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
    .sum();
  strBuilder.append(sum/(items.length - 1))
  return strBuilder.toString();
}

String out = Files.readAllLines(pathToCsvFile).stream()
    .map(x -> x.split(","))
    .map(x -> processLine(x))
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```